# Android, Firebase: minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 16

Tags: android, firebase

I need downgrade my minsdk for keep compatibility with some devices, so I need downgrade my version from minsdk16 -> 15.
But im having this error:

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller
>   than version 16 declared in library
>   [com.github.flipagram:android-assetcopier:0.1.1]
>   C:\Users\beto_.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\android-assetcopier-0.1.1.aar\7ee049aa00fd85016b1a1ae60ce050df\AndroidManifest.xml
>   as the library might be using APIs not available in 15    Suggestion:
>   use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 15,         or increase
>   this project's minSdk version to at least 16,         or use
>   tools:overrideLibrary="flipagram.assetcopylib" to force usage (may
>   lead to runtime failures)

This is my current build.grandle, but when i change the minsdk to 16, get the error showed before.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.package.id"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 510
        versionName "5.1.0"
        manifestPlaceholders = [manifestApplicationId          : "${applicationId}",
                                onesignal_app_id               : "myonesingeid",
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "myprojectnumber"]
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'go.swlib.gojni:swlib:1.0@aar'

    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.+@aar'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.0.0'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0"
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.2'
    implementation 'com.github.quentin7b:android-location-tracker:3.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
//    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
    implementation 'com.github.hotchemi:android-rate:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.flipagram:android-assetcopier:0.1.1'


}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

---

If im understanding well, my error is on this dependency :

```
implementation 'com.github.flipagram:android-assetcopier:0.1.1'
```

Hope you can help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minimum SDK level required to use the most recently versions of Firebase libraries is 16.  There is no workaround to this, other than to back up to a much older version of these libraries.

In the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) it states:

> **Prerequisites**
>
> A device running:
>
> - Android 4.1 (API level 16, Jelly Bean) or later
> - Google Play services 15.0.0 or later

Comment: so, what I can do? go down the version of firebase? can you help me with some versions for downgrade pls

Comment: And, another question, in my error from debug, doesnt say anything about firebase...?

Comment: There are a bunch of libraries that don't support less than 16.  It's really not worth trying to support those very old devices that didn't get the upgrade.

Comment: @AlbertoAcuña in your case it may not be firebase, it seems from your error its `com.github.flipagram:android-assetcopier:0.1.1` that's requiring a newer version.

Comment: @Quinn so if i remove it, maybe it can work? or downgrade some way?

Comment: You will just run into the same problem again for Firebase, and again for Play services.  They both require API level 16.

Comment: @AlbertoAcuña I don't recommend trying to remove it, as Doug said, many libraries require API level 16+, i wouldn't recommend trying to support the <1% of devices running outdated versions of android

Comment: @Quinn yes, but I need keep suporting all devices after an update, so I cant let them without service, because the app crash.

Answer (score 2):

With Android Studio open, in the menu select:

File>Project Structure

In the Project Structure window, select:

Modules then Default Config

In the Min SDK Version textfield type in 16 then hit OK

Answer (score 1):

Change the minimum SDK Level to `minSdkVersion 16`.