# i got this error while i builde my project

Tags: android, build

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller
>   than version 16 declared in library
>   [com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:20.0.2]
>   C:\Users\bushi.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\946a39d7756c6b05aa38a853bdffc128\firebase-iid-20.0.2\AndroidManifest.xml
>   as the library might be using APIs not available in 15    Suggestion:
>   use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 15,         or increase
>   this project's minSdk version to at least 16,         or use
>   tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.firebase.iid" to force usage (may
>   lead to runtime failures)

Comment: could you provide your build configuration?

Comment: It looks like you might have a 'mindSdkVersion 15' in your project, but the libraries you use, are for Sdk version 16 or newer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android, Firebase: minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55030849/android-firebase-minsdkversion-15-cannot-be-smaller-than-version-16)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `minSdkVersion 15` in your build.gradle file to `minSdkVersion 16`.

The libraries you are referencing require a later version of Android.

You can find the build.gradle file under `Gradle Scripts` in Android Studio.  The change you want to make is in the (Module: app) build file.